# Java Slick2D cmd output

Tags: java, cmd, output, slick2d

Is there any way to disable automatic Slick2D info output to CMD window showing line `INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true` every time it is used?

Besides being pretty annoying it also breaks my formatted CMD output design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your code of the class that is using Slick2D:

```
static {
    org.newdawn.slick.util.Log.setVerbose(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, works as a charm immediately - thank you!